# How to deal with Dynamic images on website

Tags: css, drupal, image

I have a website that has the functionality of dynamically loading the images. My website is getting slowed down if there are too many images (jpeg files).

How can I deal with such images ?

The website is built in Drupal.

-VJ

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically loading images? I don't understand. And some code is always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions for this type of issue, some of my recommendations are below.

1. Implement a CDN (Content Delivery Network) for your images, so they are delivered via a high bandwidth server, rather than yours.
2. Drupal has some useful tools to speed up sites, JS and CSS aggregation might do the trick.
3. I would recommend using a module called "[Imagecache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache)", this will allow you to control the size and quality of images that your users / yourself upload and display on the site.